# ARC conversion : iphone implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

```
Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

This is the error I get when trying to migrate some code to ARC with the automated tool

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                      selector:@selector(vDidFinish)
                                      name:aNotifName
                                      object:NO];
```

How can I make sure it complies with the ARC reqs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the correct type for the fourth argument (the notification sender). It expects an Objective-C object — if you don’t want to specify one, pass `nil` instead of `NO`; the latter is a literal value of type BOOL.

Comment: Let me add that if your intent were actually for the object to be a boolean with a value of `NO`, then you could box it into an NSNumber: `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`.

Comment: @Jean But `NSNumber` doesn’t post notifications.